# Difference between BlockingConnection and SelectConnection in pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am using Pika library in order to write a consumer for the RabbitMQ server. I am confused what is the difference between BlockingConnection and SelectConnection. I have read the documentation but still unable to understand what is the exact difference? I have folowing questions in my mind:

1. On the documentation, it has been mentioned that the
   SelectConnection uses the best polling method. Does it mean that if
   we create connection using SelectConnection, the consumer does not
   send acknowledgments for each message that it consumes. Instead it
   consumes a lot of message immediately and it sends only one
   acknowledgment for each message?
2. Will some kind of multithreading implemented in Pika in order to consume multiple
   messages at a time or will the messages be consumed one by one without any
   multithreading?
3. From the coding point of view, I have understood that in SelectConnection we use
   various callbacks but still I am unable to understand how SelectConnection  is fast?

Comment: I didn't read documentation but for me `BlockingConnection` can means it waits for data on socket and it can block all code but `SelectConnection` can use module `select` to check if there is new data on socket and when there is not new data then it not wait for it  (but it will check it in next loop) - so program can run other code at the same time.

Comment: @furas I have a microservice which is going to trigger a pipeline in which some machine learning algorithms will be executed when the message is received from the RabbitMQ queue. Unless there is a message I do not have any other code to execute meanwhile. Should I use SelectConnection  or BlockingConnection  because I think in my scenario it does not make any difference whether I am using BlockingConnection  or SelectConnection?

Comment: I think you should try with `BlockingConnection` because it simpler to use. To use `SelectConnection` you would have to use `asyncio` and rewrite all function to work with `asyncio` and this need more work.